# How to generate saml response use ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, dropbox, saml-2.0, cfml, lucee

I have the public key, private key, certificates files.

I want to create rsh sha1 algorithm use to create signature and Digest Value.

This is the my code

```
<cfscript>
var samlData = 
{
    NotBefore = DateFormat(DateConvert('local2utc',Now()),'YYYY-MM-DDT') & TimeFormat(DateConvert('local2utc',DateAdd('n',-1,Now())),'HH:mm:SSZ')
    ,NotAfter = DateFormat(DateConvert('local2utc',DateAdd('n',1,Now())),'YYYY-MM-DDT') & TimeFormat(DateConvert('local2utc',DateAdd('n',1,Now())),'HH:mm:SSZ')
    ,assertionId = createUUID()
    ,IDPDomain = "xxx.com"
    ,Issuer = "xxx"
    ,SPService = "dropbox"
    ,SPDomain = "dropbox.com"
    ,email = "xxxx@gmail.com"
    ,name = "xxxxx"
    ,Destination="https://www.dropbox.com/saml_login"
};
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
<cfxml variable="samlAssertionXML">
    <saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" Destination="#samlData['Destination']#" ID="#samlData['assertionId']#" IssueInstant="#samlData['NotBefore']#" Version="2.0" >
        <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" >#samlData['Issuer']#</saml2:Issuer>
        <saml2p:Status>
            <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
        </saml2p:Status>

        <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="#createUUID()#" IssueInstant="#samlData['NotBefore']#" Version="2.0" >
            <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">#samlData['Issuer']#</saml2:Issuer>
            <saml2:Subject>
                <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">#samlData['email']#</saml2:NameID>
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                    <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="#samlData['NotAfter']#" Recipient="#samlData['Destination']#" />
                </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="#samlData['NotBefore']#" NotOnOrAfter="#samlData['NotAfter']#" >
                <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                    <saml2:Audience>#samlData['SPService']#</saml2:Audience>
                </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
            </saml2:Conditions>
            <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="#samlData['NotBefore']#" SessionIndex="997f3463-8d81-4fac-ab8c-916fdc04898b" >
                <saml2:AuthnContext>
                    <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
                </saml2:AuthnContext>
            </saml2:AuthnStatement>
        </saml2:Assertion>
    </saml2p:Response>

</cfxml>
</cfoutput>
<cfset samlXML = ToString(samlAssertionXML)>
<cfset samlResponce =  replaceNoCase(samlXML, '+0000', "Z","all")>
<cfset samlXML =  replaceNoCase(samlXML, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', "")>


<cfdump var="#samlXML#" />
<cfoutput>
    <form method="post" action="https://www.dropbox.com/saml_login">
        <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value="#toBase64(samlXML)#">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" vaule="submit">
    </form>
</cfoutput>
```

this use to submit form going to dropbox saml login page and then i've faced

> could not validate saml assertion dropbox issue

Comment: What have you triéd?

Comment: @TRose I've tried to integrate dropbox sso in my web application